# To to disable a service form OS X by using recovery console?

Tags: launchd

I cannot boot my system anymore and I want to disable a service from loading and the only way to do this by using the terminal window from the recovery mode.

launchctl is not available in the recovery mode.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing a Safe Boot by holding down the shift key on boot. This will boot, but disable all login items/services. From there, you should be able to disable the problem and boot normally.

[More about a Safe Boot](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1564)
[How to perform a Safe Boot](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1455)

Answer (score 2):

Launchd controls all the services, so you can boot in single user mode and simply delete / move the files to a folder where [launchd](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/launchd.8.html) will leave them alone. (Often in single user mode you can look over /private/var/log/system.log and tell which task is hanging and be somewhat surgical about pruning launchd agents/daemons)

Here are the relevant folders from the link above:

```
FILES
     ~/Library/LaunchAgents         Per-user agents provided by the user.
     /Library/LaunchAgents          Per-user agents provided by the administrator.
     /Library/LaunchDaemons         System-wide daemons provided by the administrator.
     /System/Library/LaunchAgents   Per-user agents provided by Mac OS X.
     /System/Library/LaunchDaemons  System-wide daemons provided by Mac OS X.
```

You can also start launchd by hand (as well as load the tasks one by one manually) once you've learned how it works - I wouldn't recommend trying it for the first time on a broken mac - test and learn first on a mac that works and is fully backed up.

Comment: Could one do this in reverse? Instead of deleting LaunchDaemons from single user mode, could one move a file into the `/Library/LaunchDaemons` to have it load on next boot?

Answer (score 0):

If you've disabled certain bits in launchd ... booting OS x in safe mode wont even work.